# Why are pyglet.image and texture so heavy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, 2d, pyglet

Envrionment:

- python: 3.6.6
- pyglet: 1.3.2

Here is my code and results:

```
import pyglet

images = []
textures = []

with_textures = True
count = 10
for x in range(count):
    image = pyglet.image.load("big.png")  # 2.1 Mb source 2400*2400px
    images.append(image)
    if with_textures:
        texture_grid = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(image, 10, 10).get_texture_sequence()
        textures.append(texture_grid)

# RES in htop result without textures
# count = 10 - 300Mb
# count = 20 - 553Mb
# count = 30 - 753Mb
# count = 40 - 973Mb
# ~23Mb just for each Image

# RES in htop result with textures
# count = 10 - 996Mb
# count = 20 - 1878Mb
# count = 30 - 2716Mb
# count = 40 - 3597Mb
# ~86Mb for Image and prepared grid


input("Press enter to exit")
```

#### Questions:

1. Why each 2.1Mb file leads to 23Mb of memory usage with [pyglet.image.AbstractImage](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/image/index.html#pyglet.image.AbstractImage)?

   - If [ImageGrid](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/image/pyglet.image.ImageGrid.html) is used for creating sprite sheet -> it leads to additional ~60Mb
2. How to deal with it? Because if game contains 50+ big sprites it would be not real to dedicate such many memory only for textures.
3. Maybe there is some other approach in creating games which is used sprites? Or I should change my stack technology(pyglet as main library, also was trying with pygame) for client side?

PS: First time I've rewritten my application from `pygame` to `pyglet`, because I didn't consider some aspects of event loop in `pygame`, and now I hadn't test resource usage of `pyglet` library for my use-cases.

#### Update/clarification:

I'm using `ImageGrid` as for 3d part in vertices as for 2d part in [pyglet.sprite.Sprite](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/sprite/pyglet.sprite.Sprite.html)

Example of using in 3D part:

```
# texture_group is created once for each sprite sheet, same as texture_grid
texture_group = pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup(texture_grid, order_group)
...

tex_map = texture_grid[self.texture_grid_index].texture.tex_coords
tex_coords = ('t3f', tex_map)
self.entity = self.batch.add(
    4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS,
    texture_group,
    ('v3f', (x, y, z,
             x_, y, z,
             x_, y_, z,
             x, y_, z)
     ),
    tex_coords)
```

Example of using in 2D part:

```
pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=texture_grid[self.texture_grid_index], x=0, y=0,
                     batch=self.batch, group=some_order_group)
```

#### Update #2:

As I figure out, allowed sizes for using pyglet.image.CompressedImageData is:

```
1 True
2 True
4 True
8 True
16 True
32 True
64 True
128 True
256 True
512 True
1024 True
2048 True
4096 True
```

But can't get texture from `CompressedImageData`:

```
big = pyglet.image.load("big.png")  # 2048*2048
compressed_format = pyglet.graphics.GL_COMPRESSED_ALPHA
compressed_image = pyglet.image.CompressedImageData(
    big.width, big.height, compressed_format, big.data)
compressed_image.texture  # exception GLException: b'invalid enumerant'
```

Tried with all possible GL_COMPRESS in pyglet:

```
allowed_formats = [x for x in dir(pyglet.graphics) if "GL_COMPRESSED_" in x]
big = pyglet.image.load("big.png")  # 2048*2048
for form in allowed_formats:
    compressed_image = pyglet.image.CompressedImageData(
        big.width, big.height, form, big.data)
    try:
        compressed_image.texture
        print("positive:", form)  # 0 positive prints
    except Exception:
        pass
```

#### Update #3:

Exceptions are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-72-1b802ff07742>", line 7, in <module>
    compressed_image.texture
  File "/<venv>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 410, in texture
    return self.get_texture()
  File "/<venv>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 1351, in get_texture
    len(self.data), self.data)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

What is going in pyglet:

```
if self._have_extension():
    glCompressedTexImage2DARB(texture.target, texture.level,
                              self.gl_format,
                              self.width, self.height, 0,
                              len(self.data), self.data)
```

ipdb:

```
> /<venv>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py(1349)get_texture()
   1348             import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
-> 1349             glCompressedTexImage2DARB(texture.target, texture.level,
   1350                                       self.gl_format,

ipdb> glCompressedTexImage2DARB
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fca957ee1d8>
ipdb> texture.target
3553
ipdb> texture.level
0
ipdb> self.gl_format
'GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS_ARB'    
ipdb> self.width
2048
ipdb> self.height
2048
ipdb> len(self.data)
16777216
ipdb> type(self.data)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: I haven't done extremely complex 2D games in Python/Pyglet. But I've created things like Warcraft 1 using it without ever needing to use 2.1MB resources. I would say anything larger than 100 square pixels with 60 frames or more in each set, I would recommend you start looking at vertices and create 2D models that you actually render instead. And manipulate your bodies rather than using sprites. Because it sounds like you've gone past the use of traditional sprites (images).

Comment: @Torxed Could you please provide some examples and how to create 2D models. Which instruments should be used. Because at this moment I'm using `ImageGrid` + verticies. Like `tex_coords = ('t3f', texture_grid[self.texture_grid_index].texture.tex_coords)`. So in this approach I don't know to use except `.png` for keeping alpha layers and render sprites.

Comment: Here's a good example (and a decent library) that does 3D models in a 2D space. But you'd have to let go of the traditional PNG sprite thinking. Or, make your image resources smaller. I have no idea how complex your sprites are, but it would very well be that they're simple enough that a regular [primitives](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html) could be used. Add textures to that and you're golden.

Comment: Not sure where my hyper-link went there.. but [pyglet2d](https://github.com/hsharrison/pyglet2d) was the link I was referring to in my previous comment.

Comment: anyway, if `.png` is used -> it leads to usage of huge amount of RAM. I can't find how to "convert" `.png` into BCn formats :/

Comment: @YuriyLeonov Please show the errors it produces for each of the `allowed_formats`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb update #3 is provided

Comment: @YuriyLeonov okay… So I see 2 issues here. The first is that `GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS_ARB` is in fact [unsuitable](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCompressedTexImage2D.xhtml) for `glCompressedTexImage2D()`, so you\`ll have to choose one of the formats that fit; see [this link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.txt) and the link above. The second issue is that the image data you provide must already be encoded when it reaches that call, whereas your pixels are uncompressed. Use DXT image format instead of PNG.

Comment: @hidefromkgb I've heart many times of DXT. But how to "convert" `.png` with any DXT algorithm?

Comment: @YuriyLeonov Look [here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/Compressonator/releases) (binaries available) and [here](https://github.com/GameTechDev/ISPCTextureCompressor) (requires manual build). Don\`t try to use GIMP to export DXT, its DXT plugin is still terrible.

Comment: @hidefromkgb Thanks, because i'm trying to do all actions with image via GIMP. I'll read articles.

Comment: @YuriyLeonov BTW, don\`t forget about the [ASTC](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/ASTC_Texture_Compression) format as well. Which one of the listed compression formats will suit you better only depends on your textures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to #1 is plain and simple: PNG is a compressed format. The 2400×2400 image just has to occupy 2400×2400×32bit = 23040000 bytes in RAM after unpacking, even though its disk size is 2 MB.

Possible methods of dealing with this issue are many, but all of them boil down to finding a suitable tradeoff between memory requirements, image quality, and access speed.

For example, in Pyglet there is a class named [CompressedImageData](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/image/index.html#pyglet.image.CompressedImageData) that allows you to use GPU built-in texture compression in case you are using OpenGL for rendering. If not, you are probably stuck with implementing one of those methods in software, for PNG compression is mostly unsuitable for fast pixel access. [Here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats) you can find more info on GPU texture compression.

As a quick and dirty workaround, you can try to reduce the number of colors in your image to ≤256 and use a palette. That`ll give a 4x memory benefit right away.

Comment: I saw `CompressedImageData` and list of `compressed formats`, but I realy can't clue it with `.png` :/ I don't undertand which instrument should be used for compressing my image, for example, with `GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_BPTC_UNORM` or with any other `format`.

Comment: Added `Update #2:` in question.

Comment: @YuriyLeonov: You cannot just keep changing your question. You asked about why memory usage was not what you expected; this is the answer. If you have a new question due to that information, then you should ask that as a *separate* question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I just provide more details. My 3 questions wasn't changed since fist post. Anyway it looks solved for this moment, but I just have several clarifications. + I can't give bounty at least for 14 hours.